# Best services/soft/pool for home CPU mining today, April 2020?

Tags: cpu-mining

What's list of top sites on your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of pools, helping you to make up your own mind :)

https://miningpoolstats.stream/monero